# reading uart software on mcu - code understanding

Tags: c, function, pointers, uart

Below is code in a uart driver header file for performing a non blocking read on the uart interface.

```
/**
 * Perform a single character read from the UART interface.
 * This is a blocking synchronous call.
 *
 * @brief UART character data read.
 * @param [in] uart UART index.
 * @param [out] data Data to read from UART.
 * @return ti_uart_status_t Returns UART specific return code.
 */
 ti_uart_status_t ti_uart_read(const ti_uart_t uart, uint8_t *data);
```

Below is example code that uses the above function to get the character from the uart interface. I'm trying to understand it.

I would of thought that `ti_uart_read()` reads the character from the uart interface, hence why is there a need for `getcharacter()`?

Also why is it necessary to pass `&c` to the function? What is its function?

Many thanks

```
int getcharacter(void) {
uint8_t c = 0;
int ret;
  ret = ti_uart_read(ti_UART_0, &c);
  if (ti_RC_OK == ret) {
    return ((int) c);
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Don't use Yoda-conditions. And learning C and reading the manuals of the tools you use will help much more than asking about every detail you encounter.

Comment: What is a yoda condition?

Comment: @coffeelover, in my browser I select those two words *yoda condition*, right click and ask for an internet search. The top result takes me to a Wikipedia page explaining what it means. In this game - you have to be proactive to get anywhere.

Comment: Search engine that is.

Comment: Yoda-conditions universally disliked are not.

Comment: Using them started I to, additional safety of `==` check being reason, but frown on many people did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getcharacter` is a wrapper for the the UART function `ti_uart_read`, that handles the operation's status as well as getting the byte. `ti_uart_read` supplies two items of data: the status of the operation, and the value read. To acheive that the status was returned as the function value, and the data was set by a pointer. The reason it is done that way round, is that smoother and more idiomatic program logic can be achieved if you are checking a function's return value. Some library functions manage this all in one; `fgetc` is one example. `getcharacter` works in a similar way: it returns `-1` (data you didn't expect) in the case of an error.